# How to add textfields on uicollection view?

Tags: iphone, tableview, collectionview

i am doing a project ,where i have to show a view like this i tried to use table view ,but i was unable to implement ,after that i have decided to implement this with the help of collection view.but nothing fruitful happened .i get frustated here because nothing can happen with my view .these are the text fields added on the view and all are clickable,can anyone help me in this i am a fresher so please help me.

[image]

Comment: I think this can be done with the help of Grouped tableView. Check the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/tableviewstyles/tableviewcharacteristics.html

Comment: This can be done using tableview, customizing its cell.

Comment: @Norbert i tried it with the help of table view but was unable to implement .Please suggest me some other way

Comment: @steve Jobs i tried that also tell me how to add different textfields & those should be responsive

Comment: You can have a custom cell in the tableview. basically u need to add 8 textfields in each cell as per your requirement, assuming all the fields are editable. you can check http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ for creating custom cell. This is just an example. you can create your own as per the requirement.

Comment: thankew norbert actually i have gone through that but thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
    //////////////////
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(section==0)
        {
            return self.view_header;
        }

        return nil;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        CGFloat height =0.00;

        if(section==0)
        {
            height = 32;
        }     

        return height;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {    

        if(indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            return 51; 
        }
        else
        {
            return 35;
        }
    }



    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        if(self.flag_loadCompleted == TRUE)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  

        if(section == 0)
        {
            return [self.arr_data count];
        }
        else if(section == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTemplate";
    MyFinancialTemplate *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [MyFinancialTemplate createNewTextCellFromNib];
    }    
    cell.index = indexPath.row;  
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.index = indexPath.row;
        cell.flag_loader = FALSE;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.flag_loader = TRUE;
    }

    [cell LoadCell];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

}
```

Comment: ok i will try this.thank you  for the help,and please tell me how to get response from each textfield.

Comment: use delegates of text field